# Cookies over multiple sub domains except one

Tags: asp.net, cookies

So I know you can share your cookies across subdomains eg. **staging.mysite.com** and **www.mysite.com** etc by setting the domain of the cookies to ".mysite.com"

BUT, is there a way to share across all the sub domains EXCEPT one. e.g. the cookies will not persist on **images.mysite.com**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible and that's why sites like stackoverflow use a *cookieless* domain for static resources which is different than the main domain: http://sstatic.net

That's also part of the [recommendations of YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) for optimizing web applications.